# I'm getting a segmentation fault error in my program, but it is unclear how

Tags: c++, recursion, pi, continued-fractions

From my understanding of segmentation faults, they occur when you try to access memory outside of the "space" of the program. My IDE says the exception occurs within in the first `for` loop where I perform the following operation: `pi = w + i * i;` I don't understand how I am accessing memory that I shouldn't access. The program is supposed to compute pi, up to a given amount of digits, it is not yet complete. I was testing what I have so far when the error occurred. The code follows:

```
/// computes the continued fraction, recursivley
int w = 1;
static long double pi = 0;
long double continued_fraction(int k, int i){

    for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++){
        pi += w + i * i;
        w += 2;
        pi /= continued_fraction(k, i++);
    }

    return pi;
}

/// continued fraction method to compute pi, up to a limit k
long double limit_fraction(int k){
    int i = 1;

    /// continued fraction method
    pi = 4 / continued_fraction(k, 1);

    return pi;
}
```

Comment: The function long double continued_fraction(int k, int i){ does not make a sense because its parameter i is not used.

Comment: What inputs are you giving this? [example]

Comment: You didn't post a reproducable example, your program is not complete. Maybe k is just too large, and recursion goes too deep? I can't tell

Comment: Walk through the program in a debugger and you will probably notice that the return value of `continued_fraction` is `0` for some value of `k`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/comment-page-2/

Comment: With a rep of 65, you should already know to post a [mcve].

Comment: I see infinitive recursion for `continued_fraction`

Comment: With a large enough `i`, `w + i * i` overflows.  Consider `w + 1ll * i * i`.

Comment: LoopGod, Why passed in `i` ignored with `long double continued_fraction(int k, int i){    for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++){`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica count occurrences of `int i` in the fragment you posted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sorry misunderstood your point.

Comment: You mention an IDE that's pointing to the offending line.  The IDE should have a way to to review the call stack---i.e., all the times `continued_fraction` was called, and the parameters used, to help diagnose the function's misbehavior leading to the crash.

Comment: Recursion and mutating global variables is not a pleasant combination. Throwing a loop into that mix is usually a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Included code has infinitive recursion.

Lets call `continued_fraction(1, 1)`. Then we enter for loop which redefines `i` and set it to `1` then first iteration when it does: `continued_fraction(k, i++);` it do: `continued_fraction(1, 1)` since post-increments provides old `i`.

This call is exactly same as first call, so recursion goes forever and you have stackoverflow - crash.